# Mystery Plant ID

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found this odd rooty thing growing in one of the pots on my patio - any idea what it might be? I'm in Cape Town, South Africa, and it's the tail end of winter here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has this grown at all? If you have pictures of newer growth, it might help someone ID this plant...

Comment: Could it be a gymnosperm (cycad-group)? Just a bit visual similarity. Something else could be happen, such as a bulbous monocot.

Answer (score 5):

This is possibly some species in the subfamily [Scilloideae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilloideae). (sometimes considered as separate family called *Hyacinthaceae*). This group of plants is a subfamily of **bulbous plants** within the family Asparagaceae.

- Scilloideae are distributed mostly in Mediterranean climates, including South Africa

This subfamily contains many popular spring-flowering garden bulbs, so it would not be unlikely to see these growing up toward the very end of winter.

***Drimiopsis maculata*** seems like a fair guess at the species (or closely related to the species in the question).

[image: https://cld.pt/dl/download/1c5c2fb0-d4dd-4e02-b38d-1d7399778d3f/DSCF9402.JPG]

[image: http://www.desert-tropicals.com/Plants/Hyacinthaceae/Drimiopsis_maculata.html]

According to [here](http://www.llifle.com/Encyclopedia/BULBS/Family/Hyacinthaceae/27240/Drimiopsis_maculata), info pertaining to *Drimiopsis maculata* includes:

- Distribution: widespread in eastern South Africa
- Bulb description: Globose, fleshy, mostly exposed at the surface of the ground, about 2.5 cm in diameter and have large visible scales
- Leaves: mottled, but typically lose color to become all green.

---

I'm hesitant to provide more info because I'm still not sure about this identification. Figured I'd throw it up to see if others could rabbit-hole their way to a better answer...

Comment: wow brilliant similarity.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused right?! except for the mottled leaves.... However, I assume since the spots fade in most specimens, they could possibly be absent altogether in specific cultivars? I looked into other species in this genus (and similar *ledebouria*) but didn't find anything that looked *as* similar to the OP's pic...